# PHP multidimentional associative array performance or similar code in Java

Tags: java, php, performance

I am doing a lot of operations using a below code in PHP. The issue is PHP is getting slower and slower as my data gets bigger and bigger.

My solution to fix this is to move the code in Java so it can provide a better performance as it is complied language and I can also multithread or use async functions to do multiple such operations to make it faster.

What I want to know is how to speed up this kind of operation in PHP or what other data structure should I use to improve the performance of this code. And if not PHP how can I do this in Java.

```
        foreach ( $dataArr as $direct ) {

            //total dfpimpr for the date-li combi
            if ( isset( $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['COUNTER_TOTALIMPR'] ) ) {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['COUNTER_TOTALIMPR'] += $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
            }else {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['COUNTER_TOTALIMPR'] = $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
            }

            $dfpAdUnit = $direct['AD1']['DFPAD1'].'/'.$direct['AD2']['DFPAD2'];
            // can go on the first level of the array as not dependent on AD1/AD2-COUNTRY
            if ( isset( self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_direct'] ) ) {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISDIRECT'] = self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_direct'];
            }else {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISDIRECT'] = 1;
            }

            if ( isset( self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_ron'] ) ) {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISRON'] = self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_ron'];
            }else {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISRON'] = 0;
            }

            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DATE'] = $direct['DS']['DATE'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISADEX'] = 0;
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ISMM'] = 0;
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ADVERTISER'] = $direct['DA']['ADVERTISER'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ORDID'] = $direct['DOX']['ORDID'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['ORDNAME'] = $direct['DOX']['ORDNAME'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['LINAME'] = $direct['DLI']['LINAME'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['LIID'] = $direct['DLI']['LIID'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['LISIZE'] = $direct['DSZ']['LISIZE'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['SITEID'] = $direct['PUBSITE']['SITEID'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['COUNTRYID'] = $direct['DC']['COUNTRYID'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['COUNTRY'] = $direct['DC']['COUNTRY'];
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPADUNIT'] = $dfpAdUnit;


            //if it is passback (ISDIRECT=2) make its revenue && impr = 0
            //and add its impr to a new pbImpr column
            if ( isset( self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_direct'] )
                && self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_direct'] == 2 ) {
                //passback imprs
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['PBIMPR'] = $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
                //make dfpimpr for passback all 0
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPIMPR'] = $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPCLCKS'] = $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPREV'] = 0;
                //make tpimpr for passback all 0
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPIMPR'] = 0;
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPCLCKS'] = 0;
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPREV'] = 0;
            }else {
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPIMPR'] = $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPCLCKS'] = $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['DFPREV'] = $direct[0]['DFPREV'];
                //include direct data into 3rd party
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPIMPR'] = $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPCLCKS'] = $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'];
                $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPREV'] = $direct[0]['DFPREV'];
            }

            //include direct data into 3rd party
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TP'] = '';
            $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']]['TPTAGID'] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - level master ;) Also, if you'd obey this rule, your code would probably speed up a little.

Comment: can you please elaborate on DRY in this context?

Comment: In these cases I use HHVM. It'll run your PHP code without modification and is considerably faster and more memory efficient than PHP-CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Follow [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. That way you'll reduce the length of the code, its complexity, and - what's most important in this case - you'll get rid of several dozens of multidimensional-arrays dereferences. Also the final code will be much easier to maintain:

   ```
   foreach ($dataArr as $direct) {
       // create a few references to reduce "ugly" code
       $counter      = &$arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['COUNTER_TOTALIMPR'];
       $directStatus = &self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_direct'];
       $ronStatus    = &self::$orderLineitemSetting[$direct['DOX']['ORDID']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']]['setting']['is_ron'];

       $dfpAdUnit = $direct['AD1']['DFPAD1'].'/'.$direct['AD2']['DFPAD2'];

       if (!isset($counter)) {
           $counter = 0;
       }

       $counter += $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'];

       $e = array(
           'DATE'       => $direct['DS']['DATE'],
           'ISADEX'     => 0,
           'ISMM'       => 0,
           'ADVERTISER' => $direct['DA']['ADVERTISER'],
           'ORDID'      => $direct['DOX']['ORDID'],
           'ORDNAME'    => $direct['DOX']['ORDNAME'],
           'LINAME'     => $direct['DLI']['LINAME'],
           'LIID'       => $direct['DLI']['LIID'],
           'LISIZE'     => $direct['DSZ']['LISIZE'],
           'SITEID'     => $direct['PUBSITE']['SITEID'],
           'COUNTRYID'  => $direct['DC']['COUNTRYID'],
           'COUNTRY'    => $direct['DC']['COUNTRY'],
           'DFPADUNIT'  => $dfpAdUnit,
           'TP'         => '',
           'TPTAGID'    => 0
       );

       $e['ISDIRECT'] = !isset($directStatus) ? 1 : $directStatus;
       $e['ISRON']    = !isset($ronStatus) ? 0 : $ronStatus;

       if (isset($directStatus) && $directStatus === 2) { // Hint: don't use magic numbers (2),
                                                          // create some constant with appropriate name
           $e += array(
               'PBIMPR'   => $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'],
               'DFPIMPR'  => $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'],
               'DFPCLCKS' => $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'],
               'DFPREV'   => 0,
               'TPIMPR'   => 0,
               'TPCLCKS'  => 0,
               'TPREV'    => 0
           );
       } else {
           $e += array(
               'DFPIMPR'  => $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'],
               'DFPCLCKS' => $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'],
               'DFPREV'   => $direct[0]['DFPREV'],
               'TPIMPR'   => $direct[0]['DFPIMPR'],
               'TPCLCKS'  => $direct[0]['DFPCLCKS'],
               'TPREV'    => $direct[0]['DFPREV']
           );
       }

       $arrayToBeFilled[$direct['DS']['DATE']][$direct['DLI']['LIID']][$dfpAdUnit][$direct['DC']['COUNTRYID']] = $e;
   }
   ```
2. Optimize PHP itself. Use OP code accelerator like [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/book.apc.php) (for PHP < 5.5) or even better: a JIT compiler ([HHVM](http://hhvm.com/)) as suggested by @Alasdair